# Blurry / not sharp / pixely picture on TV (used as monitor)

Tags: windows-10, video, display, nvidia-graphics-card, graphics

I have a panasonic TV that I am using as a monitor on my desktop PC. When first bought I have used the integrated video card with a VGA cable and the best possible resolution but I wasn't happy with the quality so I have bought a DVI -> hdmi cable and then I could use it with 1920x1280 res and beautiful image. Since then I have decided to upgrade it a bit and bought a gtx 770, installed it and installed the drivers as well, now using it on the same TV with the same DVI to hdmi cable but the image on the desktop seems blurry and weird, the icons are like an 8bit image and the text is hardly readable. This is the same with a hdmi cable. The problem doesn't really appear when playing games though, when I was playing Saint's Row 3, it was great, same for CS:GO, League of Legends was not good though. I am using Win10.

Comment: Very likely upscaling/downscaling issues. Look at the resolution your monitor provides (EDID or Xorg.0.log), choose that exact resolution, if necessary with your own xorg.conf.

Comment: @Billdoe the native res for this according to the nvidia settings is that resolution.

Comment: @dirkt Thanks I will look into that in a bit more detail as I have no idea of half of the stuff you have just mentionrd

Comment: @Billdoe Yes, when you go into the nvidia control panel it tells you the native resolution for your monitor. Also, as I mentioned above I have used it already in that resolution with the integrated card and it worked well.

Comment: Thanks, will do. Whereabouts am I to find these logs?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the OS. Disregard the comments. I don't know how to debug that under Windows 10.

Comment: I have bought a HD monitor, bit smaller than the TV was but now this problem is solved. It looks like that the issue was with the TV, might be something to do with what dirkt said.